# Ошибка: 100 - не указан один из обязательных параметров, либо какой то указан не верно.

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь сформировать запрос к VKAPI, Метод: Wall.Get

В ответ код ошибки: 100 - не указан один из обязательных параметров, либо какой то указан не верно.

Делал всё по документации.

Вот запрос:

```
$id = 1;
```

$apiprov = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?v=5.23&owner_id='$id'&count=1&filter=owner");

Ответ:

```
{"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: owner_id not integer","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.get"},{"key":"v","value":"5.3"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"'1'"},{"key":"count","value":"1"},{"key":"filter","value":"owner"}]}}
```

В чем юмор понять не могу, ибо, повторюсь, всё сделано по документации.

Кто разбирается, помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А '' вам в запросе зачем?
Должно быть вот так:

```
$apiprov = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?v=5.23&owner_id=$id&count=1&filter=owner");
```

Comment: спасибо, как то проглядел)